# An instance of analyzer Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Analyzers.AvoidHtmlPartialAnalyzer cannot be created from C:\

Tags: .net-core, visual-studio-2017, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core-2.1

I'm updating a VS2017 to use ASP.NET Core 2.1 (installing dot.net core sdk 2.1 and Microsoft.Net.Compilers 2.8.2) and I am receiving some warnings about analyzers not being able to be created after creating a new ASP.net core mvc 2.1 project.

**Warnings:**

> Warning    CS8032  An instance of analyzer Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Analyzers.AvoidHtmlPartialAnalyzer cannot be created from C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.analyzers\2.1.1\analyzers\dotnet\cs\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Analyzers.dll : Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis, Version=2.8.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. Can not find the specified file.
>
> Warning    CS8032  An instance of analyzer Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.RawSqlStringInjectionDiagnosticAnalyzer cannot be created from C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.entityframeworkcore.analyzers\2.1.1\analyzers\dotnet\cs\Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Analyzers.dll : Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis, Version=2.8.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. Can not find the specified file.

Any suggestions how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I received the same message after installing dotnet-sdk-2.1.301.

Updating Visual Studio to the latest version (15.7.4) fixed it for me.

Answer (score 10):

This is my simple solution:

Unload Project -> Reload Project -> Rebuild -> Done!

Comment: This option should be the first step for anyone with the issue.

Comment: This option worked for me... I unloaded, then Reloaded, rebuild, and finally updated Microsoft.EntityFramworkCore and that did the trick... Thank you @obekir

Answer (score 3):

uninstall & installing Nuget of Microsoft.AspNetCore will resolve the issue

Answer (score 0):

I had similar errors but I wasn't using Visual Studio (using VS Code). Short of uninstalling Nuget, I cleared the local nuget cache and that worked. From the dotnet command line: dotnet nuget locals all --clear. Solved.